# CircleCI is failing to accept license for Android SDK Platform 27

Tags: android, circleci

I have the following configuration which worked for months/years, but has recently started failing on android-27

```
#
# Build configuration for Circle CI
#

general:
    artifacts:
        - /home/ubuntu/austin-feeds-me/app/build/outputs/apk/

machine:
    java:
        version: openjdk8
    environment:
        ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
        GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'

dependencies:
    pre:
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools,platform-tools,android-27
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-26.0.2
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-support
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
    override:
        - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies

test:
    override:
        - (./gradlew assemble):
            timeout: 360
```

When my circleci job runs now I get the following exception even though I am sending y to the android update sdk command.

```
IDLE<=============> 100% CONFIGURING [31s]<=============> 100% CONFIGURING [32s]Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.



<=============> 100% CONFIGURING [32s]> IDLE> IDLE> IDLE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 27].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up migrating to CircleCi 2.0. Below is a quick and dirty circle.yml file for android on circleci 2.0:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-27-alpha
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: |
                  sudo chmod +x gradlew
                  ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Build Debug
          command: ./gradlew assembleDebug
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
          destination: app-debug.apk
      - run:
          name: Uploading on Beta
          command: ./gradlew crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround:-

```
- run:
   name: Approve license for build tools
   command: (echo y; echo y; echo y; echo y; echo y; echo y) | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```